# Gulp-header plus merge-stream results in a glitch?

Tags: gulp, gulp-header

Here’s some puzzling behavior.

I want to create a gulp task that will 1) build js-files into one file using gulp-requirejs-optimize and place it into the `build` directory, 2) copy a couple of config js-files into relevant subfolders of the `build` directory, and 3) add a header to these files.

Here’s how I am attempting to do this:

In a `banner.js` file, I create a header using `gulp-header`:

```
var header = require('gulp-header');

var bannerTemplate = [
    '/**',
    ' * Hello ${name}',
    ' */'
].join('\n');

var banner = header(bannerTemplate, {name: 'world'});

module.exports = banner;
```

Then, in the file that is building javascript, I do the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var requirejsOptimize = require('gulp-requirejs-optimize');
var banner = require('./banner.js');

gulp.task('js:build:test', function() {
    // this is the entry point for our javascript files;
    // will produce a single main.js file
    var jsEntry = path.join(global.paths.jsDirectory, 'main.js');
    var options = {
        baseUrl: global.paths.jsDirectory,
        mainConfigFile: path.join(global.paths.jsDirectory,
                                  'libs/customized/requirejs/require.config.js'),
        preserveLicenseComments: false
    };
    var jsOutput = path.join(global.paths.buildDirectory, 'js');

    // I am also copying the require.js library and its customization; don't ask why
    var jsForCopy = [
        path.join(global.paths.jsDirectory, 'libs/vendors/requirejs/require.js'),
        path.join(global.paths.jsDirectory, 'libs/customized/requirejs/**/*.js')
    ];

    var requirejsOptimized = gulp.src(jsEntry)
        .pipe(requirejsOptimize(options))
        .pipe(banner)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsOutput));

    var copiedJS = gulp.src(jsForCopy, {base: global.paths.root})
        .pipe(banner) // having this line will cause a glitch
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.paths.buildDirectory));

    return merge(requirejsOptimized, copiedJS);
});
```

So here is where it is getting interesting. If I pipe through my `banner` only the stream that is building the `main.js` file (`var requirejsOptimized` in my code sample), then everything is fine — I get a `build` folder with correct files and correct structure:

[image]

if, however, I also pipe through the `banner` the stream that is copying other js files (`var copiedJS` in my code sample), then the structure of my `build` directory gets all jumbled up:

[image]

*(notice the duplication of `main.js` and the absence of the `libs` folder with its subfolders)*

So my question is, am I doing something obviously wrong with my gulp task here? Is it an expected result or is it a glitch of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't reuse the `banner` stream in both pipelines. Both pipelines are writing to and reading from the same stream. That is why the output is weird.

Instead, use a new banner stream for each pipeline:

Change `banner.js` so it exports a function that creates a new banner stream

```
module.exports = function createBannerStream() {
  return header(bannerTemplate, {name: 'world'});
};
```

In your main file invoke the function when you need a banner stream

```
var requirejsOptimized = gulp.src(jsEntry)
    .pipe(requirejsOptimize(options))
    .pipe(banner()) // <-- note the function call here
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsOutput));

var copiedJS = gulp.src(jsForCopy, {base: global.paths.root})
    .pipe(banner()) // <-- note the function call here
    .pipe(gulp.dest(global.paths.buildDirectory));
```